# What is the 'official' SEAM way of listening to JSF-SEAM phases?

Tags: jsf, seam, listener

A simple question on the title.

My case is that I want to listen to "before RENDER_RESPONSE" phase, and alter some components internal state.

Is PhaseListener the "right way" to do this in SEAM applications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want alter **JSF** component internal state, rely on JSF phase listener. Seam way of declaring JSF phase listener is shown bellow

```
@Name("applicationPhaseListener")
@Scope(ScopeType.APPLICATION)
public class ApplicationPhaseListener {

    /**
      * Called TRANSPARENTLY by Seam
      */
    @Observer("org.jboss.seam.beforePhase")
    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {


    }

    /**
      * Called TRANSPARENTLY by Seam
      */
    @Observer("org.jboss.seam.afterPhase")
    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {

    }



}
```

But if you want to alter **Seam contextual** component state, use

```
@Name("applicationPhaseListener")
public class ApplicationPhaseListener {

    @Observer("applicationListener")
    public void applicationListener() {

    }

}
```

**You can**

*Call your event programatically*

```
Events.instance().raiseEvent("applicationListener");
```

*By using @RaiseEvent annotation which is placed aboved some action method*

```
@RaiseEvent("applicationListener")
public void doSomething() {

}
```

*pages.xml*

```
<page id="<PAGE_ID_GOES_HERE>">
    <raise-event type="applicationListener"/>
</page>
```